# is there a way to run cypress tests across multiple applications via routing in angular

Tags: angular, cypress, nrwl-nx

I am using nx workspace and created two applications search-app and customer-app and both are using a lib and by using monorepos. so when I use

```
npx nx run search-app:serve-mfe
```

it runs search-app in localhost:4200 and customer-app in localhost:4201

so when a searched item is clicked it routes to customer-app by routing and opens a customer app component but it still addresses as in localhost:4200 and customer-app itself has no direct pages it can direct. all good until now

but when I am trying to write e2e tests in cypress in search-app-e2e by using

```
npx nx e2e search-app-e2e --watch .
```

I am unable to route to customer-app as it is not in listening in localhost:4201

is there a way to test pages by simultaneously call the cypress test or route through it

Thanks,
Eprogrammer

Comment: I think you should run two differents cypress tests for each application